# Проблема с переводом в WordPress + WoodMart

Tags: wordpress, интернет-магазин

В мобильной версии появляется надпись "ТУР-СТРАНЫ", как ее можно поменять? (в обычной версии такой надписи нет)
Искал в Total Commander - такие слова не найдены.
Вот строчка формирования
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См [первый коммент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329033/fatal-error-uncaught-error-function-name-must-be-a-string#comment2349623_1329033)

Comment: @SeVlad, я все в теме исправил как мне нужно было, все находилось. Осталось только это, поэтому нет смысла обновлять, так еще сам шаблон не русский.

Comment: Нда.. Не читатель.. :(

Comment: @SeVlad, а подробнее можно?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте функцию ниже в (Внешний вид - редактор тем - функции темы),

```
function tb_change_text_1( $translated_text ) {
    if ( $translated_text == 'Тур-страны' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Каталог';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'tb_change_text_1', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем такие сложности? Ведь всё дело в банальной ошибке перевода. Просто перекомпилируйте файл woodmart-ru_RU.mo. (на сайте он здесь: /wp-content/languages/themes/).

1. Откройте **woodmart-ru_RU.po** в Poedit,
2. Исправьте Тур-страны на то что Вам нужно.
3. Скомпилируйте в **woodmart-ru_RU.mo**
4. Замените исходный файл **woodmart-ru_RU.mo** по вышеуказанному адресу.