# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, wordpress

Обновляю сайт на wordpress клиенту. Обновил версию php до 7.4. При добавлении новой записи выскакивает белый экран.
Отключил все плагины и увидел ошибку.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string
in /home/mediat04/mediation.ua/www/wp-content/themes/jupiter/framework/admin/generators/option-generator.php on line 80

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открыл 80 строку этого файла и не могу понять в чём проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  foreach ( $this->options as $option ) {
        if ( method_exists( $this, $option['type'] ) ) {
            $this->$option['type']( $option );
        }
    }
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: По идее Вам нужно обернуть `$option['type']` в фигурные скобки, чтобы было `$this->{$option['type']}( $option );`. Но так как это как я понял сторонняя тема, то по идее Вашу проблему должно решить обновление темы до актуальной версии. Если же будете что-то править, то тогда естественно лучше в дочерней.